# Running ASP .NET Core on Raspbery Pi 3 B+

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, .net-core

I have trouble building working ASP .NET Core image for Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+.
Whenever I try to run the app I get the error message:

> standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"

However, when I try a pre-built .NET Core Docker Image from Github (`docker run --rm microsoft/dotnet-samples`) everything works fine.

When I've simply downloaded the same repo and built the same code with provided [Dockerfile](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/dotnetapp/Dockerfile) using `docker build . -t aspnettest-f Dockerfile` pushed it to Raspberrry and got the same error as previously:

What am I doing wrong? I've tried building the sample code with different provided Dockerfiles like [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/dotnetapp/Dockerfile.preview), but all results in the same error.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Dockerfile you need to replace `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS runtime` with `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime-stretch-slim-arm32v7 AS runtime` if building the image under Windows.

When building an ASP.NET Core App, the runtime image for ARM32 is `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-stretch-slim-arm32v7`.

Building the image on the Raspberry should work fine.

This is because `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime` is multi-arch and `docker build` choses the image that matches the current processor architecture. So, when building under Windows, the resulting image will be for amd64.

UPDATE:

Now we can use these images from the Microsoft Container Registry:

**.NET Core 2.2:**

- `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2-stretch-slim-arm32v7`
- `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim-arm32v7`

**.NET Core 3.1:**

- `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim-arm32v7`
- `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim-arm32v7`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the explanation I needed why multi-arch runtime didn't work for me first time.